# confused on how to swap the arrays in shuffling decks of cards

Tags: c

So I am confused how to reshuffle my deck of cards. I have the code written and it say that the card_t type can be assigned to an int type; and I understand that but I don't know what else to do.

```
void reshuffle(shoe_t* shoe) {
    int i, random_position = 0;
    card_t arr[52* shoe->num_decks];
    card_t temp;

    printf("SHUFFLING!\n");

    for(i=0; i< 52 * shoe->num_decks; i++) {
        random_position = i + rand() % (52* shoe->num_decks - i);
        temp = arr[random_position];
        arr[random_position] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Google "Fisher-Yates" for the correct algorithm (yours will not generate an unbiased random shuffle). Glad to see that you got rid of the srand()--presumably it's in main() where it belongs. Also you might want to print "SHUFFLING" before the loop, so it actually means "shuffling" rather than "shuffled" (though this loop is likely to be so fast it makes no difference).

Comment: Does that look better? @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: On a proper F-Y shuffle, the random position always counts down: 52, 51, 50...

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is defined to be an array of `int`s.  It looks you mean for it to be an array of `card_t`s.  You probably also want to initialize `random_position` before you use it in `card_t temp = arr[random_position]`.

Update:
You also never pass in from or return the `arr` to your main.  (Is there an array of cards in `shoe` that you're trying to shuffle?)

Comment: Did I fix it? @Joshua

Comment: I'm not a compiler :-).  Does it run?

Comment: It does run however my cards are still the same. It might be something wrong with my main. Ill check. Thanks!

Comment: See my 'Update'.  You're neither initializing nor returning `arr`.

Comment: okay I guess I don't know what you mean by initialize `arr` like do I just set it equal to zero? and yes I passed in the deck by reference, its a dynamic array. @Joshua

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're shuffling `arr`.  You create an array of the right size, but it doesn't look like you ever assign it any values or return it to the calling function.  All you ever use `shoe` for is `num_decks`.  Where is the deck data you're trying to shuffle? i.e. the one you check when you say, "my cards are still the same"?